# Use Drawable width as a value in Android Layout XML

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there any way to use the width/height of a `Drawable` as a value for any layout attributes?

Specifically I want to add a padding to my `View` that is the same length as the width of a `Drawable`.

I am aware this can be done by code but I am trying to see if it can be done in XML.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do it from the xml file itself. The only way to do it is from code. IF you set the drawable as source for an imageView (layout width must be wrap content), then in the code use the .getWidth() method to obtain the measure and set a padding equivalent to the number returned.

Another sokution is to give a fixed dp width to the imageView, use the centerCrop scaleTYpe on the imageView and then set a padding equivalent to the width of the image, directly on the xml....but I'm not sure this if this is you want to...

Comment: I figured it wasn't possible. Good to have this confirmed.